# AndroidRuntimeException on custom AlertDialog creation (ScrollView inside alertDialog)

Tags: android, xml

I want a alert dialog that displays a vertical linear layout of a textviews and edittexts, each pair on 1 line. The number of pairs can vary each time and can be upto 15-20 in number so putting that linear layout in a scroll view but i get the following exception..

```
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:229)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:234)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:337)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:355)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:260)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at edu.vesit.ams.ChoosePresetsManipAbsenteesActivity$12.onClick(ChoosePresetsManipAbsenteesActivity.java:703)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17360)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5237)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
01-04 08:25:16.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7199):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

for the code..

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {


if(editTextRollNumsMedicalLeave.getText().toString().trim().equals("") || editTextRollNumsMedicalLeave.getText().toString().trim().equals(null))
                Toast.makeText(ChoosePresetsManipAbsenteesActivity.this, "Enter atleast 1 roll number 1st", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
            {
                for(String rn:editTextRollNumsMedicalLeave.getText().toString().trim().split("[,]"))
                    medicalReasons.put(Integer.parseInt(rn), "None specified");
                final TextView txtViewsShowRollNums[] = new TextView[medicalReasons.size()];
                final EditText editTextsGetReasons[] = new EditText[medicalReasons.size()];

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChoosePresetsManipAbsenteesActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Enter Medical Leave Reasons");
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    for(int i=0;i<txtViewsShowRollNums.length;i++)
                    {
                        String medicalReason = editTextsGetReasons[i].getText().toString().trim();
                        medicalReasons.put(Integer.parseInt(txtViewsShowRollNums[i].getText().toString()), medicalReason.equals("")?"None Specified":medicalReason);
                    }
                }
            });

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(ChoosePresetsManipAbsenteesActivity.this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.setWeightSum(1.0F);

            int i = 0;
            for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry:medicalReasons.entrySet())
            {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.2F);
                txtViewsShowRollNums[i] = new TextView(ChoosePresetsManipAbsenteesActivity.this);
                txtViewsShowRollNums[i].setText(entry.getKey().toString());
                layout.addView(txtViewsShowRollNums[i], layoutParams1);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.8F);
                editTextsGetReasons[i] = new EditText(ChoosePresetsManipAbsenteesActivity.this);
                editTextsGetReasons[i].setHint(medicalReasons.get(entry.getKey()));
                layout.addView(editTextsGetReasons[i], layoutParams2);

                i++;
            }

builder.setView(layout);
                    AlertDialog alertDialogGetMedicalReasons = builder.create();
                    alertDialogGetMedicalReasons.setContentView(R.layout.medical_other_reasons_input_dialog);
                    alertDialogGetMedicalReasons.show();

        }
    }
```

Code 1st takes the numbers entered in the edittext and splits it at comma and saves each of them into a linkedhashmap of Integer keys and String values  for UID and  MedicalLeaveReason respectively .. reason originally being "None Specified"..
A custom AlertDialog is needed for getting medical leave's reasons for each student's roll number/employee number .. the dialog creates 1 textview(to show the number/UID) and 1 edittext(to get medical leave reason) per entry of linkedhashamp(both of these views are created in the for loop) ..

As there can be say 15-20 probability of medical leaves on a single day .. i need to have the linear layout(set via setview()) of edittexts and textviews inside a scrollview(set via setcontentview()) of an alert dialog

medical_other_reasons_input_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollViewActivityChoosePresets"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</ScrollView>
```

edit 1: added right after for loop

```
//alertDialogGetMedicalReasons.setContentView(R.layout.medical_other_reasons_input_dialog);
                    builder.setView(layout);
                    AlertDialog alertDialogGetMedicalReasons = builder.create();
                    alertDialogGetMedicalReasons.show();
```

edit 2: code after setting positive button

```
LayoutInflater inflater=

(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

ScrollView mainLayout = 

(ScrollView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.medical_other_reasons_input_dialog, null);

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(ChoosePresetsManipAttendanceActivity.this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.setWeightSum(1.0F);

            int i = 0;
            for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry:medicalReasons.entrySet())
            {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.2F);
                txtViewsShowRollNums[i] = new TextView(ChoosePresetsManipAttendanceActivity.this);
                txtViewsShowRollNums[i].setText(entry.getKey().toString());
                layout.addView(txtViewsShowRollNums[i], layoutParams1);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.8F);
                editTextsGetReasons[i] = new EditText(ChoosePresetsManipAttendanceActivity.this);
                editTextsGetReasons[i].setHint(medicalReasons.get(entry.getKey()));
                layout.addView(editTextsGetReasons[i], layoutParams2);

                i++;
            }

            //alertDialogGetMedicalReasons.setContentView(R.layout.medical_other_reasons_input_dialog);
            mainLayout.addView(layout);
            builder.setView(mainLayout);
            AlertDialog alertDialogGetMedicalReasons = builder.create();
            alertDialogGetMedicalReasons.show();
        }
```

Sorry if its the wrong way, just googled and tried .. havent had much experience in dynamically adding views .. i do get a scrollView with above code(i see the scrollbar) but there are no edittexts and textviews inside?

Final edit 3: after setting positive button

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.medical_other_reasons_input_dialog, null);

                    LinearLayout wrappingLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(ChoosePresetsManipAttendanceActivity.this);
                    wrappingLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                    int i = 0;
                    for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry:medicalReasons.entrySet())
                    {
                        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(ChoosePresetsManipAttendanceActivity.this);
                        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                        layout.setWeightSum(1.0F);

                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.2F);
                        txtViewsShowRollNums[i] = new TextView(ChoosePresetsManipAttendanceActivity.this);
                        txtViewsShowRollNums[i].setText(entry.getKey().toString());
                        layout.addView(txtViewsShowRollNums[i], layoutParams1);

                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.8F);
                        editTextsGetReasons[i] = new EditText(ChoosePresetsManipAttendanceActivity.this);
                        editTextsGetReasons[i].setHint(medicalReasons.get(entry.getKey()));
                        layout.addView(editTextsGetReasons[i], layoutParams2);

                        wrappingLinearLayout.addView(layout);

                        i++;
                    }

                    //alertDialogGetMedicalReasons.setContentView(R.layout.medical_other_reasons_input_dialog);
                    scrollView.addView(wrappingLinearLayout);
                    builder.setView(scrollView);
                    AlertDialog alertDialogGetMedicalReasons = builder.create();
                    alertDialogGetMedicalReasons.show();
```

Comment: Answer in long comments! :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because as the error says, you are trying to create the `AlertDialog`

```
AlertDialog alertDialogGetMedicalReasons = builder.create();
```

before trying to set the `View`

```
 alertDialogGetMedicalReasons.setView(layout);
```

So you need to call `setView()` before `create()`

Comment: would that encapsulate my linear layout in a scrollview too?

Comment: Yes, probably but I'm confused on what you have going on exactly. You are calling `setContentView()` then `setView()`. Anyway, you should be able to move `AlertDialog alertDialogGetMedicalReasons = builder.create();` to just above `alertDialogGetMedicalReasons.show();` and I think that will work

Comment: content view has the scrollview xml file reference while im trying to set the linear layout using setview

Comment: You didn't change it the way I said and please do not change your original post but you can add to it. Otherwise it becomes confusing and worthless to others. Move the `builder.create()` code to directly above the `.show()` line.

Comment: ohh ok .. but then how can i set the scrollview reference? .. builder has no setContentView()?

Comment: i changed the code .. and without any scrollview reference .. the dialog shows up but there are no edittexts and textviews inside it?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what you are doing. Why the different `Views`. Maybe you could edit your post with a little explanation.

Comment: So why do you not just inflate the `ScrollView`, create and add the `LinearLayout`, then call `setView()` using the inflated `ScrollView`? The way you are trying to do it won't work

Comment: That looks about right to me. We got rid of the error and you are getting something now. You need to check that `medicalReasons` has values when you go into the `for loop`. Set a breakpoint and debug a little to see what is going on.

Comment: uhmm yes .. i do enter a few numbers .. just did a logcat to display keys and values of each iteration .. and it did show up in logcat the 1 which i had entered(65 and 4)..
`01-04 10:11:04.869: D/65(5547): None specified
01-04 10:11:04.879: D/4(5547): None specified
` .. also the linkedhashmap gets init at start of the onClickListener

Comment: no difference .. and how can i remove `i++` .. i need to refer the edittexts and textviews again in postitive button listener to update linkedhashmap

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'm looking at it on my phone right now. I'm not sure what's going on

Comment: i guessed the problem being in linearlayout itself .. and Finally !! .. i get the editTexts and TextViews inside the alert dialog and with the scrollview too !! .. i set the width to match_parent of the 2 linear layout params instead of 0 .. its not the look i wanted but anyways i do get the views .. what i wanted was a pair of textview and edittext per line of the dialog .. here what ive got is textview on 1 line and then edittext on another and so on ....

Comment: That's because you are putting all of them in a vertical `layout` so they will be stacked. What you are looking for is to add another `LinearLayout` but inside of the `loop` and with a `horizontal orientation` and use `wieghtSum` with that and remove it from the parent `LinearLayout`. So inside your `for loop` you will create a horizontal `LinearLayout` with the `TextView` and `EditText` for each iteration and add that `LinearLayout to your `layout` which is the parent `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Ohh ok .. let me try it out

Answer (score 0):

Put this line

```
requestWindowFeature(Window. FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE );
```

before,

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ChoosePresetsManipAbsenteesActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Enter Medical Leave Reasons");
```

It might raise the exception in your case.. Because you are trying to set title to the alertbuilderdialog.. It may need windowfeature to set the title.. Let me know after you check..

Comment: I havent used any custom title .. so is that line needed?

Comment: builder.setTitle("Enter Medical Leave Reasons");   this line is to set the custom title in the aler builder right?